# make my Debian laptop switch automatically to a backup connection

Tags: debian, networking, ethernet

I have a laptop with Debian OS installed under it. It is initially connected to the internet using an Ethernet cable (via a modem) and I want to automatically switch to a backup wifi connection (which is a smartphone sharing its internet connection) whenever the Ethernet cable is unplugged.

What is the best way to have such solution? if it is using a script, how is it done?

Comment: Does it matter if the wifi connection is enabled when the ethernet cable is plugged in as long as there is no network traffic over the wifi connection?

Comment: it doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

A number of ways to do it.

Probably a dispatch script under the NetworkManager is more or less as good as any other. Just check if eth0 is up or down and then disable or enable the wifi accordingly using nmcli (the command line interface to the network manager). If you do a search you'll find the following script floating around (See for example: http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=26282):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" = "eth0" ]; then
    case "$2" in
        up)
            nmcli nm wifi off
            ;;
        down)
            nmcli nm wifi on
            ;;
    esac
fi
```

Name it what you will but /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99-wlan seem appropriate and ensure it is executable.

Some nice documentation on NetworkManager at: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager. man pages are another good source.

Can also look at netplug as well as utilizing scripts under /etc/network/interfaces as alternatives.